# In SAS, how to output at least one line in a data step when SET has zero records?

Tags: json, sas, datastep

When reading a dataset which contains zero records the data step doesn't run any put statements.

```
data test;
    set SASHELP.class end=eof;
    where 1=0;
    *output;
    if _N_=1 then put '[';
    put '"' name '",';
    if eof then put name ']';
    *output;
    run;
```

Is it possible to force some of them?

The reason I'm doing this is that I'm creating json files with put statements
(I'm using SAS9.3 and don't have access to `proc json` yet.)

The json files are completely empty when the datasets are empty. I would need them to contain at least an empty array `[]`.

This means I would need at least these two lines to run :

```
if _N_=1 then put '[';
if eof then put name ']';
```

For the moment I'm forced to split this in 3 data steps, one whith the head (`_N_=1`), one with the records, and the last with the tail (`eof=1`). Maybe there is a shorter solution?

Comment: Do your check for EOF and related action, before the SET statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is that the moment SAS hits a `set` or `input` with no record to read in, it terminates the data step at *that* point.  So since `set` is at the top of your loop, it terminates immediately.

If you move the two conditions that you want to the top, this will work, for example:

```
data test;
  if _n_=1 then put '[';
  if eof then put ']';
  set SASHELP.class end=eof;
  where 1=0;
  *output;
  put '"' name '",';
  *output;
run;
```

Then they'll operate whether or not there is data there.

Another option that I like is looping the dataset reads, but in this case it would probably be more work than is useful.